# How to add inclusions in nicolaskruchten/pivottable - example

Tags: javascript, pivot-table

I have a few columns in my json response

- year
- user
- month
- time

I'd like to build a custom pivottable with predefined values - something like year:2015 and month:06

I'm using nicolaskruchten/pivottable. I see an option for that called `inclusions` (object of arrays of strings), but I don't know how to use it. The following doesn't work.

```
$("#output1").pivotUI(mps, {
    renderers: $.extend(
        $.pivotUtilities.renderers,
        $.pivotUtilities.gchart_renderers,
        $.pivotUtilities.d3_renderers,
        $.pivotUtilities.export_renderers
    ),
    cols: ["user"],
    rows: ["year", "month"],
    vals: ["time"],
    aggregatorName: 'sum',
    inclusions {
        [{
            "rok": ["2015"]
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a colon after "inclusions"